# Varying nav slider

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, nav

I would like to create a menu nav that on large screen pushes the main body content aside but on small screens overlays the main body content. Is it possible? Here's a summary of my HTML. There's a button that toggles the javascript.

```js
const navSlider = () => {
  let menu = document.getElementById("nav_menu");

  menu.classList.toggle("hide");

};
```

```css
.overall-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-body{
  flex: 5;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide{
  flex: 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="overall-container">

<div id="nav_menu" class="sidebar">
  Some sidebar content
</div>

<div class="main-body">
  The main body
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try using `overflow` property for sidebar class.

Comment: That will handle the content inside the sidebar. My concern is if I can have a sidebar that switches between overlay and push content deepending on the size of the screen Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `position` as `absolute` in `media` with `min-width` as per your requirement of screen size will work.

```js
const navSlider = () => {
  let menu = document.getElementById("nav_menu");

  menu.classList.toggle("hide");

};
```

```css
.overall-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main-body{
  flex: 5;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.hide{
  flex: 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overall-container">

<div id="nav_menu" class="sidebar">
  Some sidebar content
</div>

<div class="main-body">
  The main body
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it out

Comment: It didn't work like I had planned so went for a different route